# How can I differentiate the following using Matrix Calculus?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

The mathematical expression is like this:

$f(\mu_{q(\beta)}, \Sigma_{q(\beta)}) = \mathbf{1}_{n}^{T} \exp \left \{ X \mu_{q(\beta)} + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{diagonal}(X \Sigma_{q(\beta)} X^{T}) \right\}$ where $\exp$ indicates element-wise exponentiation and $\operatorname{diagonal}$ is a vector with the diagonal entries of the matrix as its components. Additionally, $\mathbf{1}_{n}^{T}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with only ones as its entries and for notational ease, I used lower-case for vectors whereas matrices are in upper-case. $\Sigma_{q(\beta)}$ is symmetric whereas $X$ is not.

And I want to differentiate this by $\mu_{q(\beta)}$ and $\Sigma_{q(\beta)}$ each. So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu_{q(\beta)}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma_{q(\beta)}}$ are what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elaborate subscripts are too hard to type, so I'm going to use simpler variables and write the problem as
$$\eqalign{
  w &= \mu_{q(\beta)} \cr
  S &= \Sigma_{q(\beta)} \cr
  y &= Xw+\frac{1}{2}\,{\rm diag}(XSX^T) \cr
  e &= \exp(y) \cr
  f &= 1^Te \cr
}$$
The differentials of these quantities can be expressed using the Hadamard ($\circ$) product as 
$$\eqalign{
 dy &= X\,dw+\frac{1}{2}\,{\rm diag}(X\,dS\,X^T) \cr
 de &= e\circ dy \cr
 df &= 1^Tde \cr
    &= 1^T(e\circ dy) \cr
    &= e^Tdy \cr
    &= e^T(X\,dw+\frac{1}{2}\,{\rm diag}(X\,dS\,X^T)) \cr
}$$
Now set $dS=0$ and find the gradient with respect to $w$
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= e^TX \cr
}$$
Working out the gradient with respect to $S$ is a bit harder
$$\eqalign{
 df &= \frac{1}{2}\,e^T{\rm diag}(X\,dS\,X^T)) \cr
  &= \frac{1}{2}\,{\rm diag}(e^T):X\,dS\,X^T \cr
  &= \frac{1}{2}\,E:X\,dS\,X^T \cr
  &= \frac{1}{2}\,X^TEX:dS \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial S} &= \frac{1}{2}\,X^TEX \cr
   &= \frac{1}{2}\,X^T\,{\rm diag}(\exp(y))\,X \cr
}$$

Comment: Wow... This matrix calculus is extremely difficult. I could not have gotten it myself. Can I ask you how you studied Matrix Calculus and if there is any books or papers I can reference?

Comment: I found one problem here. The "diag" you used in the original equation that I wrote in the question was collecting the diagonal entries and making them into a vector. The last $\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}$ also has the "diag" operator only with the difference that it has a vector inside of it. Is that an operator that makes a diagonal matrix with the vector inside it?

Comment: I believe a matrix differentiation of a scalar function should be a matrix...

Comment: Yes, the name "diag" is ambiguous.  When applied to a matrix argument, it returns the diagonal elements as a vector.  When applied to a vector argument, it returns a diagonal matrix.  Sometimes I write "Diag" (with a capital 'D') to distinguish the latter function.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much :)

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to compute the Hessian of $f$ with regards to $w$ and almost came to the result but can't get through this. 
$d^{2}f = (e \circ Xdw)^{T}X$.
How can I finalise this?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities), $d^{2}f = \left( \frac{\partial e}{\partial w} \right)^{T} X$. I can't figure out how I can proceed from here.

Comment: I'm sorry for bombarding comments haha.
But I think I got the Hessian for $w$. Could you confirm my result?
$H_{w} = X^{T}\operatorname{Diag}(e)X$

Comment: Yes, your Hessian is correct.