# How can I implement Newton-Raphson's method with a function of one vector and one matrix?

Tags: matrix-calculus, computational-mathematics, newton-raphson

I have a function $f(\mathbf{u}, \Sigma)$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is a $p \times 1$ vector and $\Sigma$ is a $p \times p$ real symmetric matrix (positive semi-definite).

I somehow successfully computed the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma}$.

In this case, how do I optimize the function $f$ using Newton-Raphson's method?

=====Details=======

$y = X\mathbf{u} + \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{diag}(X\Sigma X^{T})$

$e = exp(y)$

$f = \mathbf{1}^{T} e$

where $exp$ is component-wise and $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector with ones. $X$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}\,}
\def\S{\Sigma}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556008), your gradient expressions are
$$\eqalign{
g &= \grad{f}{u} = X^Te \\
G &= \grad{f}{\S} = \frac{X^T\Diag{e}X}{2} \\
}$$
Now one can take an ADMM approach, but instead of the
($2^{nd}$order) Hessian-based Newton algorithm, use a
($1^{st}$order) gradient-based Barzilai-Borwein algorithm to solve the vector-valued subproblem, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
  du_{k} &= u_{k} - u_{k-1} \\
  dg_{k} &= g_{k} - g_{k-1} \\
  u_{k+1} &= u_{k} - \fracLR{du_{k}^T\,dg_{k}}{dg_{k}^T\,dg_{k}} g_{k} \\
}$$
where $k$ is the iteration counter.

And based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574405/357854), one can extend this algorithm
to the matrix-valued subproblem
$$\eqalign{
  d\S_{k} &= \S_{k} - \S_{k-1} \\
  dG_{k} &= G_{k} - G_{k-1} \\
  \S_{k+1} &= \S_{k} - \fracLR{d\S_{k}:dG_{k}}{dG_{k}:dG_{k}} G_{k} \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius inner product, which can be interpreted as a convenient notation for the standard trace function
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$

---

${\bf NB\!:}\,$ The initial step in each case should
be something conservative, such as
$$\eqalign{
u_\o &= u_0 - \LR{\frac{0.05\;|f_0|}{g_0^T\,g_0}}g_0 \\
\S_\o &= \S_0 - \LR{\frac{0.05\;|f_0|}{G_0:G_0}}G_0 \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X\in M_{p,p}$, $diag(V)=[v_{1,1},\cdots,v_{p,p}]^T$ and $y$ is a vector.

Consider $g:(u,\Sigma)\in \mathbb{R}^P\times \mathbb{R}^{p^2}\rightarrow (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,\Sigma),\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma}(u,\Sigma))\in \mathbb{R}^P\times \mathbb{R}^{p^2}$. To do that, we stack the matrix $\Sigma$ row  by row. For example, when $p=2$, one has $(u,\Sigma)=(u_1,u_2,\Sigma_{11},\Sigma_{12},\Sigma_{21},\Sigma_{2,2})\in\mathbb{R}^6$ and $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u},\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma})=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma_{1,1}},\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma_{1,2}},\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma_{2,1}},\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma_{2,2}})\in\mathbb{R}^6$.

We want to solve the system of $p+p^2$ equations with $p+p^2$ unknowns $g=0$; clearly, we can use the Newton-Raphson's method:

$(u_{n+1},\Sigma_{n+1})=(u_n,\Sigma_n)-(Dg(u_n,\Sigma_n))^{-1}(g(u_n,\Sigma_n))$.

Comment: Can I ask you what $D$ is here?

Comment: @ Daeyoung Lim , $Dg(u_n,\Sigma_n)$ is the jacobian matrix of $g$ in $(u_n,\Sigma_n)$; it's a $(p+p^2)\times (p+p^2)$ matrix. Its entries are the second derivatives of $f$; in other words, $Dg$ is the Hessian of $f$.