# Minimization of $\log \det$ plus $\| \cdot \|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given fat matrices ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (where $m < n$) and ${\bf B}\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ (where $p < n$ and $\mbox{rank}({\bf B}) = p$), and $m \times m$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $\bf{W}$, let ${\bf{G}} := {\bf{A}} + {\bf{XB}}$.

$$ \min_{{\bf{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}}\ \log \det \left( \bf{GWG}^\top \right) + \| {\bf{X}} \|_1 $$

where

$$ \| {\bf{X}} \|_1 := \sum_{i,j} | x_{ij} | $$

The first term of the objective function is convex under the given constraints. So this objective function is representing sum of two convex functions.

I am trying to use ADMM to write down the updating steps. However when I take $\bf{GWG}^\top$ as the the first term becomes concave. Is there a better way to formulate this problem?

Update: I tried rewriting the first term $-\log|({\bf GWG})^{-1}|$, but it complicates the update step for $\bf{X}$. Any other insights to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Update2: The log determinant term is not convex. So this problem reduces to non-convex optimization problem. Any references for algorithms which have solved similar issues?

Comment: How did you conclude the first term of the objective function is convex? It is not. This looks like a non-convex optimization problem.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes, now I think the first term is not convex. What I have checked in my derivation is the Hessian of the first term evaluated at a particular point, not everywhere.

Comment: Since no one has answered yet, there is no need to write `Update`.  Just rewrite the question incorporating what you learned since the latest edit. If comments are orphaned, so be it.

Comment: @Shana I think minimization of $\log \det (\cdot)$ seems to be bit odd. Are you in wireless communication engineering? (If yes, then I presume it is related to channel capacity, or?)

Comment: @user550103 No, I am not in wireless communication engineering. $log|GWG^top|$ is obtained after solving a multivariate normal distribution. I wanted to introduce a $l_1$ penalty to this problem to encourage a sparse solution. Have you seen any algorithms used in wireless communication which has $+ log|\cdot|$ term.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\sign#1{\operatorname{sign}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Given the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
G &= A+XB  &\qiq dG = dX\,B \\
M &= M^T=GWG^T &\qiq dM = dX\,BWG^T+GWB^T\,dX^T \\
S &= \sign X &\qiq \|X\|_\o = S:X \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Write the objective function using the above notation.
Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= S:X \;\,+\; \log\det\!\LR{M} \\
d\phi &= S:dX + d\LR{\trace{\log\!\LR{M}}} \\
 &= S:dX + M^{-\o} : dM \\
 &= S:dX + M^{-\o} : \LR{dX\,BWG^T+GWB^T\,dX^T} \\
 &= S:dX + 2M^{-\o} : \LR{dX\,BWG^T} \\
 &= \LR{S+2M^{-\o}GWB^T} : dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= \;{S+2M^{-\o}GWB^T} \\
}$$
$\|X\|_1$ isn't differentiable, so this is really a subgradient,
but it allows you to employ gradient-based methods to calculate minima with iterations like
$$\eqalign{
X_{k+1} = X_k -\lambda_k\LR{\grad{\phi}{X_k}} \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about something similar but I was not sure about how to determine the step length, $\lambda_k$. Because the paper I read for a scalar valued function should have a condition that $|\nabla f(x) - \nabla g(y)| < L|x-y|$ for differentiable function $f$ and non differentiable function $g$. I couldn't prove that the derivative of $log|GWG^\top|$ is upper bounded. Can you point to insights on selecting this $\lambda_k$?

Comment: The condition should be $|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| <L|x - y|$. Then for proximal gradient based methods $\lambda_k$ is set to $1/L$

Comment: @Shana Since this is a non-convex problem, you should try a general unconstrained method such as [Barzilai-Borwein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574405/357854) or Conjugate Gradients or L-BFGS.

Comment: As for the link you have provided: If $S_k = X_k - X_{k-1}$ and $C_k = \partial \phi / \partial X_k - \partial \phi / \partial X_{k-1}$, $\lambda_k = tr(S_k^\top C_k)/tr(C_k^\top C_k)$. Can you please point me to a paper which has obtained this expression for $\lambda_k$? I have seen something similar in quadratic programming but can't see the logic for using some similar equation here.

Comment: @Shana It's called the _Barzilai-Borwein_ step length. Google should turn up lots of journal articles. Most of them will discuss the vector case, but the extension to matrix variables is obvious.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement this algorithm. Since this is a non-convex function, how can we ensure that the solution we get after many iterations is a local minimum?

Comment: I was going through some papers about the logic behind Barzilai-Borwein step length. It looks like for a vector valued function $f$, it tries to follow $\nabla f({\bf x}_k) - \nabla f({\bf x}_{k-1}) \approx {\bf H}({\bf x}_k)({\bf x}_k - {\bf x}_{k-1})$ where Hessian H is approximated with $\lambda_k {\bf I}$. I am wondering how to write down a similar equation for matrix-valued function